# osmfilter: More simple map for a map viewer

Tags: openstreetmap

The current OSM database is so huge.

Using osmfilter, could I do it smaller for a just map viewer/GPS navigator?
For example I would only need roads, but not traffic lights.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The map viewer / navigator is existing or developed by you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just get [osmfilter](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) and keep only elements that have the `highway` key.

That should do it:

```
osmfilter osmfile.osm --keep="highway=" >streets.osm
```

If you want to process the pbf planet file from [planet.osm.org](http://planet.openstreetmap.org) you need to convert it first to the o5m format that osmfilter can use. You can use osmconvert for that.

```
osmconvert planet.osm.pbf -o planet.o5m
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas!